# Datepicker jQuery

Tags: jquery-datepicker

Tengo un inconveniente con `Datepicker` de jQuery-UI, al seleccionar la fecha no se ejecuta el evento (change), mi aplicación está hecha en AngularJS 4, y cuando se modifique la fecha ejecuta un método en mi clase, pero con datepicker no puedo ejecutarlo.

He intentado con `$(this).trigger('change')`; pero ésto únicamente busca una función JavaScript para ejecutar y no el método de Angular.

Lo que estoy buscando es como ejecutar (si es que se puede) una función Angular desde jQuery, o como notificar a ngModel que he modificado un objeto de jQuery.

Si alguien tiene una idea de que puedo hacer, les quedo muy agradecido.

```
public inicializaDatepicker() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      showOn: "focus",
      autoSize: this.tamanioAuto,
      dateFormat: this.formato,
      changeMonth: this.mesEnCombo,
      changeYear:  this.anioEnCombo,
      yearRange: this.anioMin + ':' + this.anioMax,
      onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        this.valor = dateText;
        this._value = dateText;
        console.log('SELECCIONADO --> this.valor: ',this.valor, ' --> this._value: ',this._value, '--> #datepicker: ', $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate'));
        }
    }).trigger('change');
}
```